# Drop-down is not appearing when emulated in IE 5

Tags: html, css, hover, internet-explorer-5

You can have a look of the code here, https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_dropdown_navbar

I searched for the solution, it says display property doesn't work for IE 5. Can someone suggest some solution?

Comment: Bcos CSS 3 is not supported in IE5. You can swap the dropdown with `<select>` using vanilla js/jquery for IE5 or for any specific browser agent.

Comment: More specifically, `:hover` does not exist in IE5. If you want hover functionality, you need to use a JavaScript-based dropdown which you should be able to Google for.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you need support for IE 5?